# login connection problem using SimpleTest

Tags: php, connection, simpletest, webmin

I am using SimpleBrowser from SimpleTest (http://www.simpletest.org) to login a webmin (http://www.webmin.com/). This login uses https. I've tried two different ways, both fail.

```
$browser = new SimpleBrowser();
$browser->useCookies();
$browser->useFrames();
//echoes the login page, where it should echo the landing page from a logged user
echo $browser->post('https://address/','user=User&pass=Secret'));
```

And also :

```
$browser = new SimpleBrowser();
$browser->useCookies();
$browser->useFrames();
$browser->get('https://address/');
$browser->setField('user', 'User');
$browser->setField('pass', 'Secret');
//echoes the login page, where it should echo the landing page from a logged user
echo $browser->clickSubmit('Login');
```

Do you have any clue why it doesn't work ?

Comment: Correct user/pass values. The setField lines return true, hence these fields have been successfully field.

Comment: The login page (before login) and the logged page (after login) have the same address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure if you have installed php_openssl.dll extension in your PHP.